# Close superfish menu on escape

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe, superfish

i have a problem with superfish not closing properly on escape key. It does close on escape on the first level of menu, but i have three levels and when i switch to other ones escape key event is not registering.

Here's my code, btw i'm using angular.js also:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument ||   iframe.contentWindow.document;
var htmlElement = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

    $(htmlElement).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if(event.which === 27) {
            scope.$apply(function (){
                scope.closeMenu();
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

closeMenu function does this:

```
scope.closeMenu = function () {
            $("#attrLevel").hide();
            $("#paramLevel").hide();
            $(".mbFirstLevel").hide();
            $("#contextMenu").hide();
        }
```

This works on first level of menu, but as you can see if a switch to #attrLevel escape is not working anymore. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with focus, i just focused an element on second and third level of menu with $(element).focus() and it worked.